# Nested angular http observable calls

Tags: json, angular, object, rxjs, observable

Been stuck on this problem for a little while now. What I am trying to achieve is to swap out the product ids with the http response from an api.

The appConfig response (simplified)

```
[
  {
    ...,
    hotspot: [
      {
        ...,
        data: {
          ...,
          products: [1234, 5678]
        }
      },
      {
        ...,
        data: {
          ...,
          products: [8910, 1112]
        }
      }      
    ]
  }
]
```

The code that I currently am using (really basic for now).

```
public readonly loadAppConfig$ = this._retailerSrv.retailer$.pipe(
    filter((retailer) => Boolean(retailer)),
    switchMap((retailer) =>
      combineLatest([
        of(retailer),
        this._roomConfigSrv.loadAppConfig$(),
        this._authSrv.getApiKey$(retailer),
      ])
    ),
    map(([retailer, appConfigs, authResponse]) => {
      return appConfigs.map((appConfig) => {
        this._authSrv.apiKey = authResponse.access_token;
        return {
          ...appConfig,
          hotspots: appConfig.hotspots.map((hotspotConfig) => {
            if (
              hotspotConfig.type === 'products' &&
              hotspotConfig.data.products
            ) {
              return {
                ...hotspotConfig,
                data: hotspotConfig.data.products.map((productId) =>
                  this._authSrv.getProductFromApi$(
                    productId,
                    retailer
                  )
                ),
              };
            }
            return {
              ...hotspotConfig,
            };
          }),
        };
      });
    }),
    tap(console.log)
  );
```

Which basically returns me with http observables in place of the product ids (not api responses).

Result from tap

```
[
  {
    ...,
    hotspot: [
      {
        ...,
        data: {
          ...,
          products: [Observable, Observable]
        }
      },
      {
        ...,
        data: {
          ...,
          products: [Observable, Observable]
        }
      }      
    ]
  }
]
```

I know there would be a simpler way to achieve this but I haven't found anything so far (tried promises etc). Any help would be much appreciated, and please let me know if you have any other questions.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code don't give any clue about your .json and what you want get it, but the idea it's always the same

1. you make a call to get an array
2. You create an array with elements you need search
3. you make a forkJoin of this new elements
4. you add the result to the first array

In pseudo code, use as "inspiration"

```
loadAppConfig.pipe(
switchMap(configData=>{
    ..here we has config..
    let products=[]; //we create an array with the products
    configData.hotspot.forEach(x=>{
       products=[...products,x.data.products] //we fill the array "products" 
    })
    return forkJoin(products.map(p=>loadProduct(p)).pipe( //we create an array of observables
        map(productResult=>{
            ..here change the "config" that is store in "configData"...
            ..using "productResult"...,e.g.
            configData.hotsport.forEach(x=>{
              const product=productResult.find(x=>p.key==x.data.product
               x.data.productData=product
            })
            ...finally...
            return configData
        }
    )  
}
))
```